# Testing multiplayer android

Tags: android, testing

In what way can an android game be tested considering the following constrains:

- minimal to no budget, so I cannot hire an external company to do the testing for me
- Testing should occur on multiple devices and types (phones and tablets, I have 1 available for each)
- I do not have a team of testers, nor a large group of people with android devices willing to back me up.
- The game is a multiplayer game (min 2, max 4 players per game) with a
  backend that will be hosted on an external server (which is already
  arranged), so for every testrun 2 devices are needed.
- The game server is not built in java and will be unit tested, the
  testing is more about doing integration testing.
- Optional is stress testing the game server so we can get some sort of
  baseline for this hardware.

Comment: The obvious.. get a bunch of people with Androids to run it.

Comment: read point nr 3: I dont have anyone around with an android tablet willing to help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Minimal to no budget** means you're doing it yourself.  As an indie developer, you shouldn't be considering to hire an external company to "test" for you-- this is a game, not a NASA rocket.

If you have the hardware, then you're already halfway there.  A couple of ways to gather people to test your game:

- If you live near a university or college, you might have success postering with things like "Game test volunteers needed!  Android developer needs 2-4 students who are very interested in gaming to test new multiplayer game SPROCKETS.  Game genre is RTS strategy.  PIZZA will be provided." and attach your number
- [Meetup.com](http://games.meetup.com/) might put you into contact with like-minded individuals in your area
- You might also try Craigslist (volunteer jobs) and kijiji (also asking for volunteers)